# Having max 3 checkboxes checked using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this pizza-ordering application for my final project, but I need to have the max amounts of toppings be two, so I have to limit my checkable checkboxes to two, I was thinking of doing this with Javascript  but I haven't been successfull so far, here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="texti">     
<p>Hér getið þið valið ykkar egin álegg </p><h1>ATHUGIÐ</h1><p> bara tvö álegg!</p>
</div>
<br><br> 
<div class ="col-lg-2">
    <h4> Kjötálegg </h4>
        <form action="includes/pizzaprocess.php" method="POST" name = "theform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="1" onClick="return KeepCount()">Pepperoni  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="2" onClick="return KeepCount()">Skinka  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="3" onClick="return KeepCount()">Nautahakk  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="4" onClick="return KeepCount()">Beikon  <br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="5" onClick="return KeepCount()">Auka Pepperoni  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat[]" value="6" onClick="return KeepCount()">Kjúklingur  <br> 
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <h4> Ostar </h4>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="7" onClick="return KeepCount()">Gráðostur  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="8" onClick="return KeepCount()">Cheddarostur  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="9" onClick="return KeepCount()">Extra Ostur  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="10" onClick="return KeepCount()">Lítill Ostur  <br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="11" onClick="return KeepCount()">Enginn Ostur  <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="12" onClick="return KeepCount()">Rjómaostur  <br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese[]" value="13" onClick="return KeepCount()">Piparostur  <br>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <h4> Grænt </h4>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="14" onClick="return KeepCount()">Græn Papripa<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="15" onClick="return KeepCount()">Laukur<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="16" onClick="return KeepCount()">Tómatsneiðar<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="17" onClick="return KeepCount()">Sveppir<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="18" onClick="return KeepCount()">Ananas<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="19" onClick="return KeepCount()">Jalapenos<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="20" onClick="return KeepCount()">Svartar Ólífur<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="21" onClick="return KeepCount()">Hvítlaukur<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="22" onClick="return KeepCount()">Rauðlaukur<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="greens[]" value="23" onClick="return KeepCount()">Spínat<br>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I was hoping to use javascript to limit them to two using something like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function KeepCount() 
{

var NewCount = 0

if (document.theform.meat[].checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (document.theform.cheese[].checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (document.theform.greens[].checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1}

if (NewCount == 3)
{
alert('Pick Just Two Please')
document.first,second,thinrd; return false;
}

} 
</script>
```

Please ignore the fact it's in Icelandic please, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your counter variable is getting reset to zero each time they click a checkbox.  You should move it out of the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var NewCount = 0;
   function KeepCount() 
   {

       if (document.theform.meat[].checked)
       {NewCount = NewCount + 1}

       if (document.theform.cheese[].checked)
       {NewCount = NewCount + 1}

       if (document.theform.greens[].checked)
       {NewCount = NewCount + 1}

       if (NewCount == 3)
       {
           alert('Pick Just Two Please')
           document.first,second,thinrd; return false;
       }

   } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function KeepCount() {

  // Count the number of checkmarks in each category.
  function countChecked(list) {
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var el = list[i];
      if (el.checked) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }


  var NewCount = 0


  // Check the meats
  var topping = document.getElementsByName("meat[]");
  NewCount += countChecked(topping);


  var topping = document.getElementsByName("cheese[]");
  NewCount += countChecked(topping);

  var topping = document.getElementsByName("greens[]");
  NewCount += countChecked(topping);


  if (NewCount >= 3) {
    alert('Pick Just Two Please')
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow!  If one of the answers here worked for you, don't forget to accept it using the green check mark next to it.  That will help future visitors to the question (and give some useless points to whose ever you select).

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all the onClick inline calls in your HTML if you use the following, this also will prevent subsequent checkbox options from being selected:

```
$(':input').click(function(event) {
    var count = 0;
    $(':input').each(function () {
        if (this.checked)
        {
            count++;   
        }
    });
    if (count > 2)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Pick just two please!');
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/72CGc/35/

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
<script>
    $().ready(function () {

        // your topping 'names' here
        var groups = ['meat[]', 'cheese[]', 'greens[]'];

        // for each group..
        $.each(groups, function (idx, groupName) {

            // ..find all checkboxes inside
            var $group = $('.col-lg-2').find('input[name="' + groupName + '"]');

            // and catch click
            $group.click({ group: $group }, function (event) {

                // on click event calculate sum of checked checkboxes
                var count = 0;
                $.each(event.data.group, function (idx, input) {
                    count += (input.checked ? 1 : 0);

                }); // each input in group

                // warning the user
                if (count > 2) {
                    alert('2 only!');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

            });

        }); // each topping

    });
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAsR3/